# Is there any stable Java library to perform the same set of operations on USB tokens as javax.smartcadio does?

Tags: java, pkcs11

I need to perform a public/private key generation on USB devices and store private key parts on at least 3 USB tokens.

Java `javax.smartcardio` allows to perform such an operation on Smart-cards that I plug into smart-card reader (key generation + splitting parts onto smart-cards, that are afterwards used to perform decryption).

I was wondering is there any reliable and stable Java library to do the same process, but having USB tokens instead of Smart-cards?

Comment: By "USB tokens", do you mean things like flash drives, or things like YubiKeys?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica by "USB tokens" I mean flash drives

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica so to clarify, I wish to know is it possible to perform keys generation/calculation on a flash drive's CPU, like it is done on Smart-cards (using API javax.smartcardio)